# Apache Openmeetings

Tags: openmeetings

Can someone help me to find out how we can enable "Guest" login to the Openmeeting Rooms. Whenever a recipient open a link they are forced to register on openmeeting before joining the meeting. I need the option like a recipient can join the meeting just entering the Name and/or email.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

In the Room, choose the function at the top of "Action" menu, either to send the invitation e-mail(s) or to generate the url with the invitation hash.

Answer (score 0):

You can send "Invitation"

it can be invitation to event in Calendar or "Direct Room Link". In both cases no registration is required

Comment: I tried direct link, in which is still asks for username and password to join the meeting.

Comment: unfortunately one line comments like make not much sense :( Could you describe step-by-step what do you mean by "I tried direct link"? what were your steps to get "direct link"?